# MySQL - How to optimize multiple OR conditions in a query on a large table

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Configuration (
  id: binary(16) Primary key,
  htId: binary(16),
  raId: binary(16),
  date,
  amount
);
```

I have already created these indexes:

**idx_ht** (htId) BTREE, **idx_ra** (raId) BTREE, **idx_date** (date) BTREE, **idx_ht_ra_date** (raId, htId, date) BTREE.

The table has nearly 150M records.

Here is the slow query with multiple htId-raId pairs that I want to optimize.

```
Select htId, raId, SUM (amount) as totalAmount
From Configuration r
Where ((r.htId = htId_1 AND r.raId = raId_2) 
OR (r.htId = htId_3 AND r.raId = raId_4) ... ~1000 pairs more (r.htId = htId_X AND r.raId = raId_X)) 
AND date Between fromDate 
AND toDate
Group by r.htId, r.raId
Having Count(1) = DATE_DIFF(fromDate, toDate)
Order by totalAmount ASC LIMIT 0,100
```

Is there any way to optimize the query above? Seem that the indexes do not have any affect on my query when the query has multiple ORs like that. It take a lot of time to query..
Any help will be much appreciated.
BR.

Comment: Check the query plan by using Explain.  If index is not used, you can FORCE the index scan, using FORCE INDEX option.  
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-force-index/  , 

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: `... WHERE (r.htId, r.raId) IN ((htId_1, raId_2), (htId_3, raId_4), ..., (htId_x, raId_x)) and ...`

Comment: @User2397 *If index is not used, you can FORCE the index scan, using FORCE INDEX option.* ... but remember that in most cases you do not see something that is visible to the server - in other words, forcing index usage decreases performance in most cases.

Comment: You can use use the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo\G` to give us table and indexes at the same time. The output of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` would also be useful! Something is wrong/missing here `AND toDate`. Also, `DATE_DIFF(fromDate, toDate)`  isn't [`sargable`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) - you might want to use a [simple subtraction](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4afefe71619997875b8d14cd8f341d1d) instead? You might want to convert your 1000 `OR` criteria into a table and join on that instead of having such a construct? Oh, yes, define `slow`?

Comment: What table is `raId_2` in?  Ditto for the rest of the columns without a table qualification.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Are those UUIDs?

Answer (score 0):

`OR` is hard to optimize, especially 1000 of them.

See if you can through the values in a table, then `JOIN` to that table.

Then provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Many `OR`ed predicates in the the `WHERE` (and `JOIN … ON`) clauses can be difficult to optimise for generally. They usually force index scans, or worse full table scans.

A common optimisation is to refactor all the `OR`s instead into separate `SELECT`s and then `UNION` them, like so:

```
SELECT Things 
  FROM Tables
 WHERE Condition1
    OR Condition2
     …   …
    OR ConditionN
```

becomes

```
SELECT Things 
  FROM Tables
 WHERE Condition1
UNION 
SELECT Things 
  FROM Tables
 WHERE Condition2
     …   …
UNION 
SELECT Things 
  FROM Tables
 WHERE ConditionN
```

This can be very inefficient if returning a large number of rows because `UNION` implies a sort of the resultset. If you know each filtering clause will all always return different rows to each other you can minimise this by instead using `UNION ALL`. It may not actually be practical for your ~1,000 clauses.

Of course there may be a solution with far less rearranging. *I would expect the index on `date` to help a lot for instance*. Maybe the query planner is mistakenly scanning `idx_ht_ra_date` instead thinking that will be more efficient than filtering on `date` first because the index contains all the columns filtered on. Perhaps a compound index with `date` *first* (`date, raId, htId`)<sup>[†]</sup> would help by giving it a better choice there. In fact I might be inclined to include `amount` too<sup>[†]</sup> so it doesn't need to lookup anything else as all you are filtering on and selecting out will be included in the index.

To help further people would need to see what is actually happening currently (edit the question to include the `EXPLAIN` output and other details others have already mentioned) and also how many rows you would expect to be returned each time.

<sup>[†] if you were using postgres of MS SQL Server I would suggest using the `INCLUDE` support to add the extra fields, but that isn't supported in mySql</sup>